# How would I evaluate this limit? $\lim_{x\to 3+} \frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}$

Tags: limits, radicals

How would I evaluate the following limit by hand?

$\lim_{x\to 3+} \frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By applying the appropriate techniques. What have you tried and why didn't your approach(es) work?

Comment: By first observing $x^2-9=(x+3)(x-3)$.

Comment: multiply the expression by "1"...$\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2-9}}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}\right)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \lim_{x\to 3+} \frac{x-3}{\sqrt{x^2-9}} & = \lim_{x \to 3+}\; \frac{\left(\sqrt{x - 3}\;\right)^2}{\sqrt{(x - 3)(x+3)}}\\ \\ 
& = \lim_{x \to 3+}\;\frac{\left(\sqrt{x-3}\;\right)^2}{(\sqrt{x-3}\;)(\sqrt{x+3}\;)}\\ \\
& = \lim_{x \to 3+}\;\frac{\sqrt{x - 3}}{\sqrt{x+3}}\\ \\
& = \frac 06\; = \;0\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$ \lim_{(x\to 3^+)}{\frac{(x-3)}{\sqrt{(x^2-9)}}} = \lim_{(x\to 3^+)}{\sqrt \frac{(x-3)^2}{(x-3)(x+3)}} $$

$$ \lim_{(x\to 3^+)}{\sqrt\frac{(x-3)}{(x+3)}} = \frac {3-3}{3+3} = \frac{0}{6} = 0 $$